# Does rsync establish a new ssh connection every time for multiple files or does it use the same connection?

Tags: rsync

Suppose I use rsync in the following way:

```
rsync user@server:/path/to/file1 user@server:/path/to/file2 /local/directory
```

to copy file1 and file2 from a remote server to a local directory. Does rsync in this case establish two separate ssh-connections (one per file) to copy the two files or does it establish one ssh connection and keep it open as long as necessary?

Comment: If you configure ssh to use ControlMaster/ControlSocket it'll be only one connection regardless (and would be only one connection even if you invoked `rsync` several times).

Comment: Are there now multiple ssh connections established in the case I mentioned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can trivially test this yourself, which will give you an answer valid for the specific version of rsync in use:

```
rsync -e $'sh -x -c \'exec ssh "$@"\' _' \
  user@server:/path/to/file1 user@server:/path/to/file2 /local/directory
```

(Note that the `$''` syntax used above is an extension available in ksh or bash, but not with `/bin/sh`).

You'll see a line logged by `sh -x` for each individual `ssh` command being run. If there's only one `ssh` command, then your specific version of rsync is capable of reusing the connection. (This appears to be the case in my own testing with version 3.1.2).

Comment: Thank you very much, that was exactly the kind of thing I was looking! I also use rsync version 3.1.2, which gives the result you wrote.